# Java most efficient way to replace character underscore with HTML tag <i> and close it again

Tags: java, regex

I have this input string where I want to replace the underscore with an `<i>` tag and the next underscore with a `</i>` to close it again

```
String input = "Promessa verbal: _não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra_.<br/>Permissão de falar: _peço a palavra_.";

String pretended = "Promessa verbal: <i>não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra</i>.<br/>Permissão de falar: <i>peço a palavra</i>.";

String result = input.replaceAll("_([^_]+)+_", "<i>$1</i>");

System.out.println(result);
```

Is the regular expression above the simplest or most efficient?

Comment: [NO REGEX FOR PARSING HTML!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: You have superfluous `+`s, `"_([^_]+)_"` is enough.

Comment: @JNYRanger while very true, in this case the RegEx is parsing underscores and generating `HTML`, seems like a reasonable use :)

Comment: @JNYRanger I am not parsing HTML, I am parsing a string that contains underscores. The original API already returns _ mixed with html tags http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json/palavra

Comment: I just like that post =)  @JasonSperske

Comment: @JNYRanger I do too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `+` after the capturing group.

```
String input = "Promessa verbal: _não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra_.<br/>Permissão de falar: _peço a palavra_.";

String pretended = "Promessa verbal: <i>não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra</i>.<br/>Permissão de falar: <i>peço a palavra</i>.";

String result = input.replaceAll("_([^_]+)_", "<i>$1</i>");
```

And the above regex won't replace `__` with `<i></i>` since `+` repeats the previous token one or more times . If you want your regex to do this also, you need to use `*` instead of `+` after the negated character class because `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.

```
String result = input.replaceAll("_([^_]*)_", "<i>$1</i>");
```

Comment: in my regex using the `+` actually fails if there are two underscores together somewhere, changing it to `*` fixes it by at least creating valid HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was fascinated by the part of this question about "most efficient", so I wrote this simple test (and added an answer that avoids RegExs):

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;


public class SO {
    public static String replaceSplit(String input) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        boolean open = true;
        for(int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            char c = input.charAt(index);
            if(c == '_') {
                if(open) {
                    output.append("<i>");
                } else {
                    output.append("</i>");
                }
                open = !open;
            } else {
                output.append(c);
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
    public static String replaceRegEx(String input) {
        return input.replaceAll("_([^_]+)_", "<i>$1</i>");
    }
    public static void main(String...args) {
        String input = "Promessa verbal: _não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra_.<br/>Permissão de falar: _peço a palavra_.";
        System.out.println(replaceRegEx(input));
        System.out.println(replaceSplit(input));

        {
            long start = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            for(int time = 0; time < 1000000; time++) {
                String output = replaceRegEx(input);
            }
            long end = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            System.out.println("replaceRegEx:"+(end-start));
        }
        {
            long start = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            for(int time = 0; time < 1000000; time++) {
                String output = replaceSplit(input);
            }
            long end = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            System.out.println("replaceSplit:"+(end-start));
        }

    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
Promessa verbal: <i>não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra</i>.<br/>Permissão de falar: <i>peço a palavra</i>.
Promessa verbal: <i>não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra</i>.<br/>Permissão de falar: <i>peço a palavra</i>.
replaceRegEx:4258827300
replaceSplit: 686404400
```

Or a 7X time savings if you use the more complex `replaceSplit()` approach.

Comment: my results here `replaceRegEx:2347708000
replaceSplit:899015000`, I am actually going to run the code on Android and this bit of code will not be a problem for a small body of text. The for loop approach was my first thought but since I only had one problem decided to use a regex and have two :)

Comment: I agree that the RegEx, while technically less efficient in terms of CPU time is much more efficient in terms of readability and intent, and that efficiency means it will be easier for developers to reason about and improve.  Also the regex will only replace pairs of underscores, the `replaceSplit()` function if it encountered an odd number of underscores would leave the `<i>` unclosed.  It's bugs like this that code like the regex makes clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted Avinash's answer because of the readability factor and it covers all cases I might encounter (hopefully) even though your code is the most efficient CPU wise, in my case I don't think it will ever make a difference noticeable for the use between the RegEx or the for loop.